# Post request in c # for use the Api to c#

Tags: c#, api, curl, post, http-post

I try to use the vultr api for create a server, i have succeeded the get method for get data but i don't understand how to make in post ?
This is the command for create the server:

```
curl -H 'API-Key: EXAMPLE' https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/app_change --data 'SUBID=596965' --data 'APPID=2'
```

And this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Http
{
    class Requete
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Data = "--data 'DCID=24' --data 'VPSPLANID=201' --data 'OSID=152'";
            string Reponse = String.Empty;
            StreamWriter Sw = null; // Pour écrire les données
            StreamReader Sr = null; // Pour lire les données

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/create");
                Req.Method = "POST"; // POST ou GET
                Req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; // La plupart du temps
                Req.ContentLength = Data.Length; // La longueur des données
                Req.Headers.Add("API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");


                Sw = new StreamWriter(Req.GetRequestStream());
                Sw.Write(Data); // On écrit les données
                Sw.Close(); // Puis on ferme le flux
                Sw = null;

                Sr = new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream());
                Reponse = Sr.ReadToEnd(); // On choppe la réponse
                Sr.Close(); // Et on ferme
                Sw = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) // En cas d'exception
            {
                if (Sw != null) // Si le flux est ouvert, on le ferme
                    Sw.Close();
                if (Sr != null)
                    Sr.Close();

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\r\n\r\nL'application va maintenant se terminer...");

                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Reponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data values is not correct, it should be:

```
 string Data = "DCID=24&VPSPLANID=201&OSID=152";
```

Also for easier readability, you can replace:

```
Sw = new StreamWriter(Req.GetRequestStream());
Sw.Write(Data);
Sw.Close();
Sw = null;
```

with

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Req.GetRequestStream()))
{
    sw.Write(Data);
}
```

You can do the same with the StreamReader

Comment: Merci beaucoup ça marche parfaitement